# getting error TS2339: Property 'data' in angular 5 and graphQL and apollo

Tags: angular5, graphql, apollo

i have this types

```
export type Event = {
  url: string,
  name : string,
}
export type Query = {
  events: Event[],
}
```

and i have component that fetch from graphQL

```
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {
  events: Observable<Event[]>;
  constructor(private apollo: Apollo) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.events = this.apollo.watchQuery<Query>({
      query: gql`
      {
        events(size: 200, filter: {eventType: Exhibition}) {
          count
          data {
            name
            url
          }
        }
      }
      `
    })
    .valueChanges
    .pipe(
      map(result => result.data.events.data)
    );
  }
}
```

with this code i can fetch the data and show him in template but still when i compile i get 
ERROR in src/app/components/list/list.component.ts(31,40): error TS2339: Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Event[]'.
and data in the pipe code is with red underline. 
i new in angular so i try couple of thing and didn't succeeded, i need to know why get this error . thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you said, query event type defined on server is something like:

```
export type Query = {
  events: Event[]
}
```

which means event query would return an array of event object having `url` and `name` fields.

Now coming to call being made from your angular code, there are two issues I notice:

1. It is expecting fields `count` and `data` in response of `events` query but since those fields are not present in `events` type defined at server, you are getting error.
2. Also, you have passed `size` and `filter` arguments to the query but they have not been defined in corresponding graphQL type on server and since query being made is not respecting schema, it will throw an error.

Following code should work fine,

```
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {
  events: Observable<Event[]>;
  constructor(private apollo: Apollo) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.events = this.apollo.watchQuery<Query>({
      query: gql`
      {
        events {
          name
          url
        }
      }
      `
    })
    .valueChanges
    .pipe(
      map(result => result.data.events)
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

solution : 
the problem was that i didn't build my type accordingly to the answer that i get from the graphQL
the new types :

```
export type Query = {
  events : Events,
}

export type Events = {
  count: number,
  data : Event[],
}

export type Event = {
  url: string,
  name : string,
}
```

and the query :

```
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {
  events: Observable<Event[]>;
  constructor(private apollo: Apollo) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.events = this.apollo.watchQuery<Query>({
      query: gql`
      {
        events(size: 200, filter: {eventType: Exhibition}) {
          count
          data {
            name
            url
          }
        }
      }
      `
    })
    .valueChanges
    .pipe(
      map(result => result.data.events.data)
    );
  }
}
```

hope it can help somebody